# ng-model is not updating when the value is set from javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am calling a javascript function in my code and there setting the value of the textbox. The value is getting updated but its not binding to ng-model.
Below is the code for the same :-

```
<input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" ng-model="pojo.name"/>
<a href="" onClick="lookup('id','num','name1','null', 'form');return false"><img name="popup" src="/docs/images/lookup.gif"/></a>
        {{pojo.name}}
```

In the javascript the code is as below:-

```
function lookup(d, a, b, c, frm){
        fName = frm;
        lookup1(d, a, b, c);
    }
```

This above function is calling many other javascript functions after some code processing we are setting some value like below.

```
function lookup1(d, a, b, c)
{
 document.getElementById(d)='abc';
}
```

This is getting mapped to the html textfield but not reflecting in the ng-model.

We cannot change the javascript code and need to use the same code.

Comment: share in fiddle...

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use onClick with agularjs. It won't work. You need to use`ng-click` and that should bind to a function in controller or directive. And there you should update variable that is binded via ng-model.